# Get Column name from a query table

Tags: ms-access, vba

With normal tables, I can access the column name using the

```
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '" & Tbl & "' "
```

and it works...

but during the execution of VBA code I also need to retrieve columns name not from tables, but from the table resulting after a query, how can I get that in VBA?

```
Dim Qry as QueryDef
Dim MrgTbls as QueryDef
Dim T1 as String
Dim T2 as String
Dim SQLJoin as String
```

...

```
Set MrgTbls = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(Qry.Name, SQLJoin)
```

...
and later on I want create a query such as

```
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'MrgT'
```

which returns nothing since the table MrgT is not in INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS, unlike other tables.

Comment: Can you add more detail? What objects are you working with? E.g. rs.fields(i).name

Comment: As an aside, `Dim T1, T2, SQLJoin As String` defines two variables of type `Object` and only one of type `String`. Also, if `QryName` is of type `QueryDef`, how can you assign a string to `QryName`?

Comment: How do you use `SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA_COLUMNS` on an Access database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the column names from a `QueryDef`, you can use the `Fields` collection:

```
Dim firstColumnName As String
firstColumnName = MrgTbls.Fields(0).Name
```

Alternatively you can use pure SQL and the `MSysObjects` and `MSysQueries` system tables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329223/what-does-the-data-in-msysqueries-mean) for details about the structure of this table.